# Is there a way to get the keys in a dictionary as their original type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dictionary

I am very new to typescript and I have the following dictionary where the the keys and values are float arrays:

```
start_to_end_dict
> {-121.95131592,37.253239074: Array(2)}
> -121.95131592,37.253239074: (2) [-131.950349087, 47.253099466]
> [[Prototype]]: Object
```

I want to get a list of the keys as a list of arrays like this:

```
> [Array(2)]
> 0: (2) [-121.95131592, 37.253239074]
> length: 1
> [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

But then I get a list of strings instead:

```
Object.keys(start_to_end_dict)
['-121.95131592,37.253239074']
```

I noticed that `values` seems to get a list of arrays:

```
Object.values(start_to_end_dict)
> [Array(2)]
> 0: (2) [-131.950349087, 47.253099466]
> length: 1
> [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: all keys in JS are strings.

Comment: Object keys in JS are, by spec definition, strings. They cannot be anything else.

Comment: you might want to look into Map()s, or use an array of arrays (`[ [1.2,3.4],[5.6,7.8]]`) instead. Or just turn the string into a number: `Object.keys(start_to_end_dict).map(Number)`...

Answer (score 0):

As noted by other users in comments on your question: keys of objects are always `string`s in JavaScript. You can write a function to parse the string coordinates, and then [iterate over the entries of the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), using it to parse the numeric coordinate values from each key, while accessing the (already parsed) values directly:

> An explanation of the regular expression below can be accessed [here](https://regexr.com/6l02q).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9nATgEwM5QLxQNoDsCuAtgEYSIA0UBJZAugNwCwAUCwMZy6rBQdJoAlCAHMIAD0xQA9AD0AOqgBUACgD8AHlwBGAHwBaVWoBcc5AGo5AOgCUi02esLF5J2s0AmfYdUnzV2-aOSgAkUkyszABm+LhswACWnFBgAIaIqBDw-OjK3IjxuMJZKKhGUHkFwtZlxWhQAN4sULyc3FDCiHD4YOhYFYW1qJaEKcBsABbKfCVComLWqpYdXT3hzfGRUMoAhMvdqNZQwOOdAO5UEOcAooidiMoA5LUFoxDokUgjPLhwPABuKQANvFkA9rGsWlweNM6lhsHsepZtJQEUNcO5aMMUmBlAA5IikRCHFLoQYQxAQYD4RC4FrZcIAXxYLCkUigABVxvF0NyjuNoHBiAArCBxKAAwH4aDHUZQEBdcrjOCnCDIKAFPnQACOUu4iVwRnYrR44hShDAgIgABFRikykIOCh1P1hJRBjpJI1mM0HnotO4tJYAJwAVi0AGYtCGg+5yOGAOyWdwh8PucNBgAM8YALA8ytg-ZHgyGM+Hs5mABzxyjZxPJ8MZoNB7MANhbtHILAZ4RYH0QWw4UJwAGsICBKBKpbQoHBNgB5YWi4CWCC4YD5N7KU3my024ApayHL3NQdtUcgQaSVLpTIIErKc-gpqQ1BwS2WQFwYTKernwYToEpUGMpJwgBkn2YJlmCAA)

```ts
type Coords = [number, number];

const coordsRegex = /^\s*(?<n1>-?(?:\d+\.)*\d+)\s*,\s*(?<n2>-?(?:\d+\.)*\d+)\s*$/;

function parseCoords (stringCoords: string): Coords {
  const groups = stringCoords.match(coordsRegex)?.groups;
  if (!groups) throw new Error('Coordinates format not valid');
  const coords = [groups.n1, groups.n2].map(Number) as Coords;
  return coords;
}

// This is the object value that you showed in the question:
const exampleData: Record<string, Coords> = {
  '-121.95131592,37.253239074': [-131.950349087, 47.253099466],
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(exampleData)) {
  const keyCoords = parseCoords(key);
  console.log({keyCoords, valueCoords: value});
}
```

Compiled JS from the TS playground above:

```js
"use strict";
const coordsRegex = /^\s*(?<n1>-?(?:\d+\.)*\d+)\s*,\s*(?<n2>-?(?:\d+\.)*\d+)\s*$/;
function parseCoords(stringCoords) {
    const groups = stringCoords.match(coordsRegex)?.groups;
    if (!groups)
        throw new Error('Coordinates format not valid');
    const coords = [groups.n1, groups.n2].map(Number);
    return coords;
}
// This is the object value that you showed in the question:
const exampleData = {
    '-121.95131592,37.253239074': [-131.950349087, 47.253099466],
};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(exampleData)) {
    const keyCoords = parseCoords(key);
    console.log({ keyCoords, valueCoords: value });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
const start_to_end_dict = {
  '-121.95131592,37.253239074': [-131.950349087, 47.253099466]
};

const arr = [];

Object.keys(start_to_end_dict).forEach(key => {
    key.split(',').forEach(elem => arr.push(Number(elem)))
});

console.log(arr);
```